# Postgres integer value not updating by formula

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to change the value of an integer field using a formula but it never sets the correct value:

```
update "inventory" set "price" = round("cost" + ("cost" * (50 / 100)), 0) where "id" = 1
```

In this case, `cost=1000` so I expect `price=1500` but instead I get `price=1000`.

Am I missing some math nuance of Postgres here?

PostgreSQL 9.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division is tricking you. `50 / 100 = 0`. Try `50. / 100.`, this gives the expected result of 0.5.

Comment: Nuance confirmed. Thanks!

Comment: It's not really a nuance, it's more about expected types.  In PostgreSQL when a number is written as `100`, the type `integer` is assumed.  To force an `integer` to a `float` you would need to do something like `100::float` or `CAST(100 AS float)`.  As per the answer though, `100.` is probably sufficient

Comment: Not something I ran into in MySQL. Usually, just using `round()` was sufficient. Good to know in any event.